# Some elements not visible in browser in svg image

Tags: browser, svg, visibility

I have [svg file exported from flash](http://images.jcubic.pl/girl-with-flask.svg), I can open that file in Inkscape and I see clouds and a girl. In browsers the girl is visible but the clouds not. In svg they are the same `symbol` in `defs` with two groups, and a `use` element with `xlink:href`

The cloud that are not visible look like this:

```
  <defs transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) ">
    <symbol id="Symbol__202" viewBox="0 0 94.9 52.4">
      <g id="Warstwa.__202">
        <g id="group1">
          <path id="path27" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="1" d="M440.5,18.3 Q440.5,15 438.1,12.6 C436.55,11.05 434.7,10.3 432.5,10.3 430.25,10.3 428.35,11.05 426.75,12.6 426.15,13.25 425.65,14 425.25,14.8 425.2,11.1 423.85,7.95 421.25,5.35 418.6,2.7 415.35,1.35 411.5,1.35 407.75,1.35 404.55,2.7 401.9,5.35 400.35,6.9 399.3,8.6 398.65,10.45 397.3,9.6 395.75,9.2 394.05,9.2 392.6,9.2 391.25,9.5 390.05,10.15 389.9,7.8 388.95,5.8 387.3,4.1 385.5,2.25 383.3,1.35 380.7,1.35 378.15,1.35 375.9,2.25 374.05,4.1 372.8,5.4 371.95,6.85 371.55,8.5 368.95,6.85 366,6.05 362.7,6.05 358,6.05 353.95,7.7 350.6,11.05 347.25,14.45 345.6,18.5 345.6,23.25 345.6,27.95 347.25,32 350.6,35.45 353.95,38.8 358,40.45 362.7,40.45 366.9,40.45 370.55,39.1 373.7,36.45 372.1,38.4 371.3,40.65 371.3,43.2 371.3,46.1 372.3,48.55 374.35,50.6 376.5,52.7 379,53.75 381.85,53.75 384.75,53.75 387.25,52.7 389.35,50.6 391.4,48.55 392.45,46.1 392.45,43.2 392.45,42.65 392.4,42.2 392.35,41.75 393.3,41.3 394.25,40.7 395.15,40.05 395.7,42.65 397.05,44.95 399.1,47 402,49.9 405.5,51.35 409.55,51.35 413.65,51.35 417.15,49.9 420.05,47 421.05,46.05 421.85,45 422.5,43.85 423.65,44.25 424.85,44.45 426.1,44.45 429.1,44.45 431.65,43.35 433.75,41.2 435.9,39.1 437,36.55 437,33.55 437,30.7 436,28.25 434,26.15 435.55,25.85 436.9,25.1 438.1,23.95 439.7,22.4 440.5,20.55 440.5,18.3z M385.45,18.8 L385.45,18.9 385.35,18.9 385.45,18.8z M375.5,34.75 C375.7,34.45 375.9,34.2 376.15,34 376.2,34.05 376.25,34.1 376.25,34.25 376,34.4 375.75,34.6 375.5,34.75z"/>
          <path id="path28" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M440.5,18.3 Q440.5,15 438.1,12.6 C436.55,11.05 434.7,10.3 432.5,10.3 430.25,10.3 428.35,11.05 426.75,12.6 426.15,13.25 425.65,14 425.25,14.8 425.2,11.1 423.85,7.95 421.25,5.35 418.6,2.7 415.35,1.35 411.5,1.35 407.75,1.35 404.55,2.7 401.9,5.35 400.35,6.9 399.3,8.6 398.65,10.45 397.3,9.6 395.75,9.2 394.05,9.2 392.6,9.2 391.25,9.5 390.05,10.15 389.9,7.8 388.95,5.8 387.3,4.1 385.5,2.25 383.3,1.35 380.7,1.35 378.15,1.35 375.9,2.25 374.05,4.1 372.8,5.4 371.95,6.85 371.55,8.5 368.95,6.85 366,6.05 362.7,6.05 358,6.05 353.95,7.7 350.6,11.05 347.25,14.45 345.6,18.5 345.6,23.25 345.6,27.95 347.25,32 350.6,35.45 353.95,38.8 358,40.45 362.7,40.45 366.9,40.45 370.55,39.1 373.7,36.45 372.1,38.4 371.3,40.65 371.3,43.2 371.3,46.1 372.3,48.55 374.35,50.6 376.5,52.7 379,53.75 381.85,53.75 384.75,53.75 387.25,52.7 389.35,50.6 391.4,48.55 392.45,46.1 392.45,43.2 392.45,42.65 392.4,42.2 392.35,41.75 393.3,41.3 394.25,40.7 395.15,40.05 395.7,42.65 397.05,44.95 399.1,47 402,49.9 405.5,51.35 409.55,51.35 413.65,51.35 417.15,49.9 420.05,47 421.05,46.05 421.85,45 422.5,43.85 423.65,44.25 424.85,44.45 426.1,44.45 429.1,44.45 431.65,43.35 433.75,41.2 435.9,39.1 437,36.55 437,33.55 437,30.7 436,28.25 434,26.15 435.55,25.85 436.9,25.1 438.1,23.95 439.7,22.4 440.5,20.55 440.5,18.3z"/>
          <path id="path30" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M385.45,18.8 L385.35,18.9 385.45,18.9 385.45,18.8z"/>
          <path id="path35" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M375.5,34.75 C375.75,34.6 376,34.4 376.25,34.25 376.25,34.1 376.2,34.05 376.15,34 375.9,34.2 375.7,34.45 375.5,34.75z"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  ...
  <use xlink:href="#Symbol__202" id="Symbol.__203" width="94.9" height="52.4"
       x="0" y="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 813.15 14.5)" overflow="visible"/>
```

and is the same as a girl

```
<use xlink:href="#dziewczynka" id="dziewczynka1" width="80.1" height="187.8"
     x="-40.05" y="-93.9" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 50 200)" overflow="visible"/>
```

I tried to remove the dot from ID in the cloud but it didn't change anything. Why the clouds are not visible in the browser?

Comment: Opera shows the clouds. Which browsers are you using?

Comment: @RobertLongson IE, Google Chrome and Firefox for windows